# Python Flask with SQL connection

Tags: python, mysql, database, authentication, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import MySQLdb.cursors
import bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret key'


# Enter your database connection details below
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'host'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'pythonlogin'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def password_reset():
    msg = 'asd'
    # Check if "username", "password" and "email" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'new_password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        new_password = request.form['new_password']
        email = request.form['email']

        #check if the account exist in the database
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute( "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s", (username,))
        account = cursor.fetchall()

        #if the account exist in database
        #the code goes in here
        if account:
            if account['username'] == session['username']:
                salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=16)
                hash_password = bcrypt.hashpw(new_password.encode(), salt)

                sql = "UPDATE accounts SET password = %s WHERE username = %s "
                val = (hash_password, username)
                cursor.execute(sql, val)

                mysql.connection.commit()

                msg = "You have successfully changed the password! "

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # Form is empty... (no POST data)
        return 'Please fill out the form!'
        # Show registration form with message (if any)

    return render_template('password_reset.html', msg=msg)
```

Hi I am Using the SQL connection to do this and what I am trying to do is resetting the password of a user, where the user enter in their username, old password, new password and email. Then I tried to get the user information based on what the user entered in the form.

For example the  user entered 'john' in the forms, and the form is there to check if there is any user name 'john' in the database, then if there is a 'john' in the database, my python code should replace the old password in the database with the new password the user entered in the form

the code I have done fails to compare the username in the database with what the user entered in the form. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the very old school of doing apps (hard coding `SQL` statements ..) in general and it's not the recommended way to do modern `flask` apps. There are many `3rd packages` out there (well documented) that can make your application very easy to develop, robust and even more secure. i would recommend you those commonly used 3rd packages:

- `Flask-SQLAlchemy` for sql and models ..
- `Flask-WTForms` for forms
- `Flask-Login` for authentication / registration

Below the reviewed code:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import MySQLdb.cursors
import bcrypt
import re 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret key'

# Enter your database connection details below
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'host'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'pythonlogin'

mysql = MySQL(app)

# add route name 
@app.route('/reset-password', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def password_reset():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # since username and email are uniques for any given account, you can use one of them or 
        # even better, using only the 'username' field, the user can enter his username or email
        # and then check wether the input of 'username' field is a username or an email (with 
        # simple regexp or 3rd package) so you can make the form more compact and more UI/UX friendly. 

        username     = request.form['username']  # as label for this field : "enter your usernme or email")
        password     = request.form['password']
        new_password = request.form['new_password']
        email        = request.form['email']
        
        # flag to check errors
        error = None

        # check if the 'reset password' form is filled and all parameters are posted
        if not username:
            error = "Username is required."
        elif not password:
            error = "Password is required."
        elif not new_password:
            error = "New Password is required."
        elif not email:
            error = "Email is required."
        elif not re.search('^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$', email):
            error = "Email is not valid."


        if error is None:
            # check if the account exist in the database
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute( "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s OR email = %s", (username, email))
            account = cursor.fetchone()  # to get the first record

            # if the account exist in database
            # the code goes in here
            if account:
                salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=16)
                hash_password = bcrypt.hashpw(new_password.encode(), salt)
                
                sql = "UPDATE accounts SET password = %s WHERE username = %s "
                val = (hash_password, username)
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                
                mysql.connection.commit()

                flash("You have successfully changed the password!", "success")

                if account['username'] == session['username']:  # if the user is already logged in
                    return redirect(url_for("dashbord"))  # redirect to dashboard
                return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))  # if not logged in, redirect him to login page 

            else:
                error = "The username / email don't match our records."

        # you don't need to pass the error / success mesaages to render_templte, use flash()
        # you can add an extra parmeter 'success' or 'error' to make difference and disply 
        # properly the right 'alert' message (if you re using Bootstrap for e.g)
        flash(error, 'error')

    return render_template('password_reset.html')
```

use the code below in you main layout to display `flash()` messages based on their categories `success`, `error`

```
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
      {% for category, message in messages %}
      <div class="alert alert-{% if category == 'error' %}danger{% else %}{{ category }}{% endif %} alert-dismissible fade show rounded-0" role="alert">
        <strong class="text-uppercase">{{ category }}!</strong> {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
```

and finally, there are many github repositories for starter `Flask` apps you can refer to theme for your next projects, for e.g:
https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base

Comment: I am very thankful for all your help and comment, I am doing this way because it is required by my school so I have no choice but to apply it.

Comment: @LiangJin no problem, anyway even the `Flask` official tutorial (https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/1.1.2/examples/tutorial) is made the old way.
if you find my answer useful for your case, would you mind give it a green tick ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your code little bit

The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set and returns a list of tuples. If no more rows are available, it returns an empty list.
so the fetchall will give something like  [(),()] you need to take the first element,

or you could use cursor.fetchone() that will give you a single record or None
you get this kind of result a tuple () of as row something like this

`(1, 'Emma', 'emma@pynative.com', 'asdasd',)`

and you need to put right index to access your username from database  like  `account_name = account[your_acccount_name_index]`

and match `account_name == username  == session['username']`